# Adobe Animate cc 2017 - HTML5 freezes when I publish/test project with audio

Tags: html, audio, adobe, createjs

Adobe Animate cc 2017 - HTML5 freezes when I publish/test project with audio

I'm working on a small game, using Animate 2017 and exporting it to HTML5. I'm using `createjs.Sound` to add the sound fx I've added to the library. When I publish or "test" the project, it freezes the loading bar. On OSx it stays at 0%, on windows it goes up to 70% but freezes anyway. The only option being to force quit the app. I'm following a tutorial from Pluralsight, and I've tested the tutor's project and I get a slightly different issue, the project gets published, the browser starts everything automatically but nothing happens afterwards, instead of the game starting, it just stays a black canvas (no errors in the console).

A few more data to help troubleshoot, the tutor's project is using .mp3 files and I'm using .wav audio. I've been trying to look through the OSX auto generated error report, but I can't make heads or tails of what it says.

- Animate mac/windows version - 2017.0.1 Release (16.0.1.119)

Comment: Can you share the published files?

Comment: I'm not sure I can @Lanny, the project is part of a paid course in pluralsight. But the issue is now resolved, it seems it was some corrupt the symbols that caused the crash. Converting the project to AS3 and then back to HTML5 fixed it. I'm still unsure what caused the issue in the first place, but at least I know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a corrupted symbol or something that was causing the program to crash. Converting the project to ActionScript 3 and then back to HTML5 solved the issue.

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2425008

Answer (score 0):

If anyone experience a AnimateCC crash issue in Mac, It might be an issue with long audio file name. I found that if the audio file name is greater than 29 characters, AnimateCC crashes when publishing. Here is a sample test file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dEBdM4laszCXFa3Bz4tS3yHh-8PbLaGo/view?usp=sharing

As you can see, the file crashes when you try to export. It has only one sound file in the library. When you remove one character in the file name, it gets published successfully. I tested this in AnimateCC version 18.0.2 (Build 126).